# Can I use Ant to set some static variables in my Android project when building?

Tags: java, android, ant, build, replace

I would like to automate my Android project building with Ant. Currently I have to change some static String and Boolean fields in one of the classes for different kind of versions of the same app for different markets.

Is it possible to set these variables with Ant, without resorting to copying a file with some strange markers in it? I want to be able to keep using the files in Eclipse.

Comment: I recommend to generate an unique Properties file, but leave the source unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can*, but you shouldn't.  Don't make your Ant build file mess with the code; it leads to strange and confusing errors that are hard to find.

Instead, use [java Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Here's a little example of how a `static final` can be initialized in a `static` block:

```
class Junk {
    public static final int j ;
    static {
        // Use java.lang.Properties here to get the values 
        j = 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv){
        System.out.printf("The answer is %d\n"  , j);
    }
}
```

Comment: A good option, of course this leads to the inevitable need to explicitly call ClassLoader.getResource(...) which isn't a bad thing, but a bit awkward considering how well (and invisibly) Java loads classes.

Comment: Nah.  Just load your properties in a static block.

Comment: I guess you're talking about a properties file that's not internal to a JAR.  It seems to me that if this was to track strings that were specific to the version of an app, it would be a good candidate for including in a JAR file (or in this case an APK).  Am i missing something here?  If so, I'd be very interested.

Comment: I'd hadn't really considered it, but wouldn't you use "getResourceAsStream"?

Comment: I used this option. I generate a properties file with ant, save it as a resource file and then compile everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

When copying, use a filterset.  Include a few filter tokens to be replaced in the text file, and in the filterset specify the token and the value to replace it.

```
 <copy todir="../backup/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
    <filterset>
      <filter token="TITLE" value="Foo Bar"/>
    </filterset>
 </copy>
```

Note that you must do this prior to attempting to compile the file, so you might have to rework a bit of the compiling logic to be compatible with the filtered copy.

Personally, I make a build/processed-src directory and copy everything into it filtered (copy will only update out-of-date files) and then rework the compile chain to compile from there.

Comment: I didn't notice the "without some strange markers", did you see that you can user select the markers in question?  Does that help in any way?  Do you want Ant to rewrite the file in-place?

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm going to accept the markers. I have converted my Android app build process to Ant, and will try approach. Altough the properties are also interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can create a stub "java" file which is "echo"ed out as part of the ant build.

```
  <echo file="com/corp/product/Version.java">
     package com.corp.product;

     public class Version {
        public static final int MAJOR = ${version.major};
        public static final int MINOR = ${version.minor};
        public static final String full = "${version.major}-${version.minor}";
     }
  </echo>
```

It gets around most of the complaints about having to copy, but it does mean that the class will have to be maintained within the ant build file (or in an included ant build file).

Comment: Every approach has weaknesses, with this one you're writing out the whole file.  If you are willing to restructure your clases, it might be a good option.  Note you would have to "build" the Version source code prior to IDEs / compilers looking for the java file.